# reading the firebug console in javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium, firebug

I'm looking for a way to read the most recent command that was logged to the firebug console.

For example, I could have something that does

```
console.debug('The most current request URI is /sweatsocks');
```

And then another piece of (pseudo)code could then

```
if (mostRecentConsoleEntry().endsWith('/sweatsocks')) {
  // do some stuff
}
```

The context being the debug statement would be in the code under test, and the console checking would be done inside a selenium script. This would let me observe information buried deep in js functions as well as stuff that is built at runtime.

Comment: "The most current request URI is /sweatsocks" - that's the grossest URI i've ever heard.

Answer (score 5):

You could overwrite the `console.log` function to add whatever extra functionality you need.

```
var oldLog = console.log;
var lastLog;
console.log = function () {
    // do whatever you need to do here: store the logs into a different variable, etc
    // eg:
    lastLog = arguments;

    // then call the regular log command
    oldLog.apply(console, arguments);
};
```

This won't be the most bulletproof solution, since `console` allows printf style syntax:

```
console.log("%d + %d = %s", 1, 3, "four");
```

...but it's probably a start for you.

Comment: That's what I wished I knew :) +1

Comment: It don't work in FF3 and Firebug 1.3.3 since console.log is read-only. Also you are not allowed to add properties to the console object.

Comment: The syntax for apply is .apply(thisobject,array), so if it had worked to change the console object, it should have been: console.oldLog.apply(console.oldLog,arguments); but I suggest using a selfexecuting function to store the private variable with instead.

Comment: The printf style syntax actually still works fine, why wouldn't it?

Comment: @nickf - Would this (or a more complete implementation of the console object) stop logging of Firefox modules to the console? I get out of memory errors on resource:///modules/sessionstore/SessionStore.jsm and was hoping that I could use Javascript to probe the console periodically for this error, to warn me if when the browser finally crashes (As I don't shut it down often, and am a heavy internet user) that it will not restore with session data from that time (Which is what I am seeing)?

Comment: @user66001 no, this wouldn't work for that. The approach above overwrites the `log` method, but I doubt that internal errors and warnings would use the same interface. You could try it though.

Comment: And what about line numbers? Is it possible to get them?

Answer (score 2):

Don't try and override console.debug, implement a function that does console.debug plus what you need.

```
var debugCalls = [ ];
function myDebug(errorMessage){
  console.debug(errorMessage); //maintain original functionality
  debugCalls[debugCalls.length]  = errorMessage;
  //the previous argument to myDebug is debugCalls[debugCalls.length]

  //you may also want to call an ajax function to report this error
  mailError(errorMessage);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you rewrite the `console.log()`, and append all logs to an array? Then fire up the original `console.log()` and repeat what it's doing to get your debug output on the console?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more elaborate version I put together:

```
/**
 * Console log with memory
 *
 * Example:
 *
 *     console.log(1);
 *     console.history[0]; // [1]
 *
 *     console.log(123, 456);
 *     console.history.slice(-1)[0]; // [123, 456]
 *
 *     console.log('third');
 *     // Setting the limit immediately trims the array,
 *     // just like .length (but removes from start instead of end).
 *     console.history.limit = 2;
 *     console.history[0]; // [123, 456], the [1] has been removed
 *
 * @author Timo Tijhof, 2012
 */
console.log = (function () {
    var log  = console.log,
        limit = 10,
        history = [],
        slice = history.slice;

    function update() {
        if (history.length > limit) {
            // Trim the array leaving only the last N entries
            console.history.splice(0, console.history.length - limit);
        }
    }

    if (console.history !== undefined) {
        return log;
    }

    Object.defineProperty(history, 'limit', {
        get: function () { return limit; },
        set: function (val) {
            limit = val;
            update();
        }
    });

    console.history = history;

    return function () {
        history.push(slice.call(arguments));
        update();
        return log.apply(console, arguments);
    };

}());
```

Comment: Update: Added Object.defineProperty logic so that setting console.history.limit trims it immediately instead of after the next log() call (just like internal Array length does)

Answer (score -1):

You might wanna implement a queue. Expanding on Devin's answer: (something like this)

```
var window.log = [];

logger function(msg) {
  var log_length = 10;
  console.log(msg);
  window.log.push(msg);
  if(window.log.length > log_length) {
    window.log.shift()
  }
}
```

See:
[How do you implement a Stack and a Queue in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590247/how-do-you-implement-a-stack-and-a-queue-in-javascript)
http://aymanh.com/9-javascript-tips-you-may-not-know#string-concatenation-vs-arrayjoin