# Javascript: how to loop through an array upon each call

Tags: jquery, arrays, function

I am trying to create a function that upon each call it chooses the next variable in an array.

```
var nexttest=['abc','def','ghi'];
function nexttest() {
 if (nexttest = 'abc') {
  $('#result').load('url1.html');
 }
 else if (nexttest = 'def') {
  $('#result').load('url2.html');
 }
 else {
  $('#result').load('url3.html');
 }
}
```

Is there a way to make nexttest() use abc the first time, def the second time, and ghi the third time.

Comment: Do you really mean just one `=` in `if` and `else if`??

Comment: Although either of the approaches that have already been provided would work fine if you don't need to maintain the nexttest array you could just pop values off each time you call your function. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590247/how-do-you-implement-a-stack-and-a-queue-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it more like

```
var tester = function(){
    var i = 0;
    var tests = ['abc','def','ghi'];
    this.nexttest = function() {
        if (tests[i] == 'abc') {$('#result').load('url1.html');}
        else if (tests[i] == 'def') {$('#result').load('url2.html'); }
        else { $('#result').load('url3.html');}        
        i++;
    };
}

var testing = new tester();

testing.nexttest();
testing.nexttest();
testing.nexttest();
testing.nexttest();
```

​

Comment: Keith, thanks for your advice.  Do you know how I would call this function from an iframe?  I have been trying parent.testing.nexttest() and window.parent.testing.nexttest() but neither is working.

Comment: Nevermind. parent.testing.nexttest() works fine, it was just the difference in protocols messing it up because I was viewing my site with SSL and loading the iframe with http://...oh well, figured it out now (time wasting done.)

Answer (score 3):

You would create a variable that keeps track of the index of the array:

```
var index = 0;
```

Then, in the function, you could select the array element you want to interact with using the `index` variable:

```
var interactWithThis = nexttest[index];
```

And then increment the index each time the function is called:

```
index++;
```