# javascript message queue

Tags: javascript, associative-array

I am using javascript to create a message queue, say for example I want to store the messages "hello" and "word" to user with id "123", I am using the following to set and retrieve them.

```
var messages = [];
var userId = 123;

messages[userId].push("hello");
messages[userId].push("word");
```

needless to say, this is not working, damn arrays! How can I make this work, keeping it as simple as possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Exists here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1590262/1519323

Comment: {} is an objecct, [] is an array

Comment: @laser_wizard: that's not quite what I want to do. I want to then be able to access the message list of a particular userId

Comment: @Diodeus: I know, I'm just getting crazy litterally! trying to get assoc arrays working for me has always been a pain and this evening I really am offline!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an array (`[]`) for every user:

```
var messages = {};
var userId = 123; 
messages[userId] = ["hello", "word"];
```

You can use `push` too:

```
var messages = {};
var userId = 123; 
messages[userId] = [];
messages[userId].push("hello");
messages[userId].push("word");
```

Comment: Thank you. This works. What about *getting* a particular userId's message queue?

Comment: @johnsmith: `messages[userId]`

Comment: The `userId` is a property of the `messages` object, you can just do `messages[userId]`, or `messages[123]`.

Answer (score 2):

`messages[userId]` does not exist.

You need to put an array there:

```
messages[userId] = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

well, technically you could push elements as properties of an object, which you have created and then iterate thorugh its properties.