# Javascript Binary search tree using stack and queue

Tags: javascript, stack, queue

I have to write a program which will find the lowest common ancestors but I have to use stack and queue. I am trying to learn on my own and just solving all the interview questions from the web can anyone help me get started? just need a template and I can fill out the meat of the program.

Comment: *"I am trying to learn on my own."* You won't learn on your own if we just hand you the code.

Comment: I am not even asking for a code I would just like a small pseudo code or even just main // code here function //stuff it does here or something like it. I have hard to time starting from scratch I have felt if I see something like a template or know which function to code it makes it easier for me to code.

Comment: Javascript can be run from a console. There is no `main` method like in Java or C. If you open Chrome Developer Tools or Firebug (either can be opened with F12), you can open a console window and run scripts from there.

Comment: Okay thanks I will try it out and see what happens. Hopefully fail then succeed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To implement your stack and queue you can use a simple array. The array object in javascript has commands like push(sth) or pop().

For more informations, take a look @ http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_array.asp

Also check this out: [How do you implement a Stack and a Queue in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590247/how-do-you-implement-a-stack-and-a-queue-in-javascript?rq=1).

I hope you can start from here. learning by doing is the best way to learn sth. ;)