# Are that.push and that.pop elements of "that={}" object literal?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there a specific reason to use "that?"

Note about using "that": 
I found a thread explaining "that" :[What does 'var that = this;' mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886632/what-does-var-that-this-mean-in-javascript).  One of the respondants said: "By convention, we make a private that variable. This is used to make the object available to the private methods. This is a workaround for an error in the ECMAScript Language Specification which causes this to be set incorrectly for inner functions." Thus, I am confused if the "that" here has any special usage.

In addition, Why not simply assign a var name to replace that.push? Thank you very much.

```
var LinkedList = function(e){

  var that = {}, first, last;

  that.push = function(value){
    var node = new Node(value);
    if(first == null){
      first = last = node;
    }else{
      last.next = node;
      last = node;
    }
  };

  that.pop = function(){
    var value = first;
    first = first.next;
    return value;
  };
  var Node = function(value){
    this.value = value;
    var next = {};
  };

  return that;
};
```

Comment: 2 is a javascript object, with the firstName and lastName properties.

Comment: Javascript objects can be considered as key/value arrays. http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/

Comment: More correctly, javascript Arrays are Objects with a special length property. Objects are simple collections of key/value pairs, as are Arrays. Neither have any sense of order.

Comment: The LinkedList object is trying to implement a queue in javascript. More info here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590247/how-do-you-implement-a-stack-and-a-queue-in-javascript

Comment: I edited my question to be more specific.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.  :)

Answer (score 2):

> (1) is array of string

Yes, that is correct. However, as there is no strict typing in Javascript a better description would be an array containing strings. The array isn't limited to containing strings just because it is created with only strings in it.

> (2) is array of object

No, that's not correct. It's an object, so it contains properties. Each property is an name and a value.

An object is not an array, but an array is actually an object. An array can have items, but it can also have named properties.

The `LinkedList` function creates an object that has `push` and `pop` methods just like an array, but the items are stored differently than in an array.

Answer (score 1):

As noted above, (2) is a javascript object with properties, and therefore doesn't contain standard array methods of push and pop. The code is creating a custom object called LinkedList, that has push/pop behavior, but couldn't be an array as it would conflict with the methods of an array.

Answer (score 0):

> Question 1: … (2) is array of object. Is that right?

No. As commented by Zack, #2 assigns an Object to the *x* variable.

> Question 2: Assuming what I understood is right above,

Unfortunately it isn't.

> Could someone explain why the code below wants to create that.push and [that.pop] and then store them in the that object ---- that = {}?

The code assigns an Object to *that*. Objects don't have *push* or *pop* methods. The design apparently calls for the object returned by *LinkedList* to have such methods, so they are added.