# Find matching parenthesis on page using javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to find the matching parenthesis on the same page and highlight both.

eg...

function foo(){
    //test
};


So when I click on the '{' I want to be able to find the corresponding parenthesis '}' and highlight both on the webpage.

how can I achieve this using javascript/jQuery?

Comment: Whatever syntax/language you're showing on the page, you'll need a parser for it if the data could be more than your simple example. Furthermore, what needs to be done will depend on the markup in the page itself.

Answer (score 0):

To find those chars, use:

```
var a = str.indexOf("{");
```

Then use:

```
var b = str.indexOf("}", a);
```

Finally use [How to highlight text using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644428/how-to-highlight-text-using-javascript)

Comment: for a little more comlex example like { { } }

Comment: We need to implement a stack and parse the text, how can that be done in javascript

Comment: found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590247/how-do-you-implement-a-stack-and-a-queue-in-javascript

Comment: You found your answer. Just use array to save indexes then use them for highlighting. But parse the text, needs a parser as @squint said about that.