# AngularJS - Make synchronous http request

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-http

**Angular Service**

```
this.sendCommand = function (someData) {

                URL = myURL;
                return $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: URL,
                    data: someData
                }).then(function (response) {
                    return response.data;
                }).catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error)
                });
            };
```

Use Case: User can send multiple commands by clicking on a button. For example, request 2 should not return response until request 1 response is fulfilled. How do I make synchronous call using above snippet, so that even if user clicks on a button multiple times, the request being sent will be served in queue ?

Comment: Why should the use case require synchronous requests?

Comment: @HardikVaghani: The $http functions  already return a Promise object themselves. This means there’s really very little need to create a new deferred and pass the associated promise back, much less having to handle the resolving and rejecting code as part of your service logic.

Comment: @zeroflagL: coz the component receiving the request is able to serve single request at a time.

Comment: I understand that, but the request itself doesn't have to be synchronous.

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be handled better with a boolean variable. As javascript is single threaded you could just create a variable 'isWaitingForResponse' and add an if to send the request only if there is no other in progress.

```
this.sendCommand = function (someData) {
    if (!this.isWaitingForResponse) {
        this.isWaitingForResponse = true; 
        // do request
        .then(
            this.isWaitingForResponse = false;
        );
    } else {
        // don't send request
    }
};
```

If you really want to queue the requests you could use a javascript: queue [stackoverflow queue question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590247/how-do-you-implement-a-stack-and-a-queue-in-javascript). Then your code would look like this:

```
this.sendCommand = function (someData) {
    if (!this.isWaitingForResponse) {
        this.isWaitingForResponse = true; 
        // do request
        .then(
            this.isWaitingForResponse = false;
            // check if there is a request in a queue
            // if there is: invoke this.sendCommand
        );
    } else {
        // don't send request
        // put request in a queue
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a spinner to block user clicking the button before the previous request is completed.