# Does javascript have objects/containers like stack and queues?

Tags: javascript, stack

Learning about data structures in details. Checked few js tutorials online and they seemed to use array for everything.

Like this:

```
class Stack { 

    // Array is used to implement stack 
    constructor() 
    { 
        this.items = []; 
    } 

    // Functions to be implemented 
    // push(item) 
    // pop() 
    // peek() 
    // isEmpty() 
    // printStack() 
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you implement a Stack and a Queue in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590247/how-do-you-implement-a-stack-and-a-queue-in-javascript)

Comment: Yes. Javascript arrays behave like linked lists in low-level languages

Comment: `Array::pop()` and `Array::shift()` let you handle an array as stack or queue

Comment: A stack - use a regular array and use the `.push()` and `.pop()` methods. A queue - use a regular array and use the `.push()` and `.shift()` methods. Almost everyone simply use the arrays directly instead of wrapping them in an extra object layer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there is no existing object containers for the likes of stack and queue but there are a handful of techniques on how you efficiently implement them.

refer to these links: 
https://chevtek.io/9-javascript-tips-you-may-not-know/
https://yuiazu.net/2019/02/19/stack-and-queue-in-javascript/

hope this helps :)