# Calculate angle based on x, y position

Tags: javascript, math, arrows, atan2

I am trying to calculate the angle for an arrow on a ball, based on the position where it is going to.
The arrow moves, but in a total unexplainable direction, can anybody give some pointers?

Codepen available: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/rayio/pen/LYYjGON)

I added the full code on here (EDITED based on input):
I added a step to make the difference bigger for the angle calculation, not sure if that is the right way to go, but it seems a bit more functional. Plus added the +/- 90 in the angle method, but that doesnt seem to fix it. It is still feeling odd.

```
class Throwable {

  constructor(){
    this.throwObject = null;
    this.canDrag = null;
    this.initialDiffX = 0;
    this.initialDiffY = 0;
    this.previousX = 0;
    this.previousY = 0;
    this.intervalCounter = 0;
  }

  set x(input) {
    this.throwObject.style.left = input + 'px';
  }

  set y(input) {
    this.throwObject.style.top = input + 'px';
  }

  set rotation(input) {
    this.throwObject.style.transform = `rotate(${input}deg)`;
  }

  init(){
    this.throwObject = document.querySelector('.throwable');
    this.throwObject.addEventListener('mousedown', this.activateDrag.bind(this));
    this.throwObject.addEventListener('mouseup', this.deactivateDrag.bind(this));
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', this.drag.bind(this));
  }

  activateDrag(event) {
    this.canDrag = true;
    this.initialDiffX = event.clientX - this.throwObject.offsetLeft;
    this.initialDiffY = event.clientY - this.throwObject.offsetTop;
  }

  deactivateDrag() {
    this.canDrag = false;
  }

  drag(event) {
    if(this.canDrag === true) {
      if(this.intervalCounter >= 30) {
         this.intervalCounter = 0;
      }
      if(this.intervalCounter === 0) {
        this.previousX = event.clientX;
        this.previousY = event.clientY;
      }
      this.intervalCounter++;
      this.y = event.clientY- this.initialDiffY;
      this.x = event.clientX - this.initialDiffX;
      this.rotation = this.angle(event.clientX, event.clientY, this.previousX, this.previousY);
    }
  }

  angle(ex, ey, cx, cy) {
    var dy = ey - cy;
    var dx = ex - cx;
    return Math.atan2(dy, dx) * 180 / Math.PI + 90;
  }

  // Untility
  log(logObject) {
    let logStr = '';
    for(let key in logObject) {
      logStr += `${key}: ${logObject[key]}<br>`;
    }
    document.getElementById('log').innerHTML = logStr;
  }
}

let throwable = new Throwable();
throwable.init();
```

I made a mistake in comparing two different values, I fixed that, it is working way better, still have some odd behavior sometimes, seems like it doesnt know where to go in some points. But working better than before.

Comment: The ```angle()``` function is returning a value in degree, are you sure that this is what ```this.rotation``` is expecting?

Comment: Yes its expecting degrees:

`
  set rotation(input) {
    this.throwObject.style.transform = `rotate(${input}deg)`;
  }
`

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you have some mistakes in your angle function. This works for me:

```
angle(cx, cy, ex, ey) {
    var dy = ey - cy ;
    var dx = cx - ex ;
    return Math.atan2(dx, dy) * 180 / Math.PI;
}
```

Comment: Math.atan2() expects the first parameter to be the y position.

Comment: True, the first argument passed must be the Y, followed by the X.
I think the mistake must be somewhere else, if you can take a look at the codepen, you can see the weird rotation behavior.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because there's a difference how angles are measured between `Math.atan2()` and the CSS rotate transformation.

For us humans it's natural that the 12 o' clock position on an analog clock refers to the angle 0 - same for CSS rotate.

Math.atan2() however measures the angle starting from the horizontal x axis. So depending on your input coordinates it would be the 3 or 9 o' clock position.

There's an easy fix however.
After calculating the angle

```
Math.atan2(dy, dx) * 180 / Math.PI
```

just subtract 90 degrees like

```
Math.atan2(dy, dx) * 180 / Math.PI - 90
```

Comment: I added it, but instead is subtracting, I added the 90, like Herman suggested, otherwise it would behave counter-clockwise.

Comment: Yes, this happens because angles range from -180 to 180 and not 0 to 360 (and the order of your input vertices is important too).

Answer (score 0):

When you call `this.angle()` you give it twice `this.throwObject.offset...`, once directly and once via `px` and `py`:

```js
let px = this.throwObject.offsetLeft;
let py = this.throwObject.offsetTop;

this.rotation = this.angle(this.throwObject.offsetLeft, this.throwObject.offsetTop, px, py)
```

That will result in `dx` and `dy` to be `0` in `angle()` making the result of `Math.atan2()` unpredictable.

I'm not sure about the rest of your code, but maybe you meant to call `angle()` like this:

```js
this.rotation = this.angle(this.x, this.y, px, py);
```

Comment: I am getting the X-Y and store that in px-py, then I set the new values, so basically the previous are stored in px-py.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple small issues that I can see.

First, the angle method is calculating radians in range of -180 to 180 and you want it to be 0 to 360. So after angle calculation you'll want to convert something like this:

```js
angle(ex, ey, cx, cy) {
    var dy = ey - cy;
    var dx = ex - cx;
    var theta = Math.atan2(dy, dx) * 180 / Math.PI;
    if (theta < 0) theta += 360; // convert to [0, 360]
    return theta;
}
```

Second, the starting angle of your element at 0 degrees is not the actual 0 degrees calculated by this method due to how js coordinates work. A quick fix is to add 90 degrees to make it match:

```js
set rotation(input) {
    this.throwObject.style.transform = `rotate(${input + 90}deg)`;
}
```

It's still a little janky after these conversion but I think it's a start on the right calculations. My guess is part of the issue is having such close points for calculation.

Comment: Thank you Herman, I tried a few solutions, also yours, but its for some reason still not working properly, I added a step interval to make the distance a little bigger for comparisons.

Comment: Can someone explain the +90 offset? When calculating the position based on sin/cos, then reconverting to the angle using tan2 my angle is off by -90 degrees.

Comment: After flipping the `ex - cx` arguments when calculating `dx`, I no longer needed the -90 degree offset.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when `intervalCounter` become 0? The previus point moved to the event point, so `dy`, `dx` becomes 0 and you have a jitter: `-180 + 90`, `+180 + 90`, `0 + 90` [as defined in Math.atan2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/atan2). After that, the previus point is fixed until `intervalCounter < 30` and you have some inceasing distance between the previus and event points, so the angle is close to the expected one.

Anyway, this is a bad coordinate filter. You can improve it by implementing simple [exponential filtering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_smoothing) or by using fixed size (30 in your case) [queue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1590247/6547185) for event point.