# Get content From the Firebug console?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you programmatically access the Firebug console output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375522/can-you-programmatically-access-the-firebug-console-output)

I wanted to know if it was possible to retrieve the Firebug console's content (with javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I suppose it wouldn't be too tricky, from the firebug console you can populate element in the DOM. So I guess writing a firebug extension that when ever anything is written to the concole it also writes it to the DOM.

The from javscript, you can pull it out of the DOM.

But I don't think you can do this without an extension.

However you may wish to take a look at firebug lite, as that I believe is in the DOM directly. So you possibly could detect changes to the firebug lite div's in your code.