# JS/jQuery: Is it possible to extract content from the browser's console?

Tags: javascript, jquery, console

When I do `console.log(info)` is it possible to later use JS to extract everything from the browsers console and add it to a `var`? I would like to extract all contents of the console and send it to the server through AJAX

Basically I'm looking for something like:

```
var console_content = console.read();
```

Is there anything in JS or jQuery that will make this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you programmatically access the Firebug console output?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375522/can-you-programmatically-access-the-firebug-console-output)

Answer (score 1):

instead of writing to the console (which you really shouldn't do in a production environment) why not just push each thing you want to log to an array and then pass it to the server with a PUT when you want to?:

```
var _log = [];

//instead of console.log(message)

_log.push({message:'message goes here'});

//using jquery because it's easier
function pushAjax(url, data, callback, method) {
    return jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: method,
        data: data,
        success: callback
    });
}

//call your push function when you want...
pushAjax('www.yourserver.com',_log,'PUT',successFunction);
```

Comment: What about errors that are reflected in the console that you didn't log? E.g. library generated errors, or when some exception occurs?