# Is there a way to read the console.log using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, console.log

The title is pretty self-explanatory..

Is there a way to read whatever's been output to the console.log up until the moment you decide to read it, using Javascript?

Comment: Not standard, no. One could monkey-patch `console.log` to use an internal queue (and also write-through) - or perhaps look into browser/extension specific support (e.g. any Firebug hook?).

Comment: Maybe this could help you move in the right direction? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601363/reading-the-firebug-console-in-javascript

Comment: @user2246674 I think your comment is good enough to be an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make a proxy around it, such as :

```
(function(win){
    var ncon = win.console;

    var con = win.console = {
        backlog: []
    };

    for(var k in ncon) {
        if(typeof ncon[k] === 'function') {
            con[k] = (function(fn) {
                return function() {
                    con.backlog.push([new Date(), fn, arguments]);
                    ncon[fn].apply(ncon, arguments);
                };
            })(k);
        }
    }
})(window);
```

Comment: But I have to be quick enough to override the console before some script for example starts using it, otherwise I'll lose whatever that script logged up until the moment I start overriding the console. Also, if a script uses "delete console;" my override will be lost, correct? So I'll need to set an interval to keep overriding the console, hoping that no logs are lost between those intervals, right?

Comment: I don't think you can actually loop over the properties of `console`.

Comment: @SproutCoder: `delete console;` is not a common line of code.  If a script did that, I'd be worried what else it was doing.  I wouldn't waste your time with an interval.  As for being "quick enough", just load this as the 1st script on your page, that way you can be sure it's first.

Comment: `for(var k in console) if(typeof console[k] === 'function') console.log(k)` seems to work at least in chrome.

Comment: @OneOfOne: It wasn't working for me before for some reason.  Worked this time :)

Comment: @SproutCoder at any given point only one piece of code will be running, unless you're using something async (xhr mainly), if you add this piece of code before anything else, you will be fine.

Comment: I can certainly override the console like so : `var arrayLog = []; console.log = function (x) {arrayLog.push(x);};`. However, if at some point during the logging process a script uses `delete console;` my assignment will be lost so I'll need to `var grabConsole = setInterval(function (){console.log = function (x) {arrayLog.push(x);};},30);`

Comment: @RocketHazmat I was checking `typeof k` instead of `typeof ncon[k]`, my bad.

Comment: @SproutCoder: Like I said, I really wouldn't be worried about `delete console;`.

Comment: @SproutCoder if a script tries to delete console, something is very wrong.

Comment: I work with web analytics and I come across asynchronous tags all the time.I've never seen external tags use delete console to behonest, but I've come across websites that use it just because they don't like it I guess, but you're right I can't be paranoid about it